# Not sure why I am getting a StackOverflowError. Also have a yellow underline under Vector, and 1 other place in code

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am getting:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at tesseract.MazeApplet.reshape(MazeApplet.java:60)
    at java.awt.Component.setBounds(Unknown Source)
    at tesseract.MazeApplet.reshape(MazeApplet.java:60)
    at java.awt.Component.setBounds(Unknown Source)
```

And that repeats all the way down.
This is the code that gives the error:

```
public void reshape (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
    setMaze();
}
```

Also, I am getting a yellow underline beneath stop() on this code:

```
private void stopThread (int index) {
    if (threads[index] != null) {
        threads[index].stop();
        try { threads[index].join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        threads[index] = null;
    }
}
```

I am not really sure why. However I added a @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") to get rid of the underline, and it hasn't come up as a problem.

Another spot has the same yellow underline in a separate class beneath Vector:

```
private Vector  pending;
```

And here:

```
if (pending.size() > 10  &&  prob(dens))
            pending.setElementAt(sq, pending.size() - 1);
        else  // not pruning, add pending Sqr to list
            pending.addElement(sq);
    }
```

And here:

```
pending = new Vector();
    maze[startX = 0][startY = rint(mzHyt - 2) + 1] = FLOOR;
    dirtySquare(startX, startY);
    pending.addElement(new Sqr(startX, startY, RIGHT, false, false, false, true));
```

I would greatly appreciate all the help you all can give.

Comment: Lack of details which are required to solve the question!!!

Comment: Please post a part of the exception stacktrace. Usually, for a stack overflow, it will be very long, but there should be a few lines repeating over and over again. Please post those lines.

Comment: `I am not really sure why. However I added a @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") to get rid of the underline` Facepalm

Comment: It seems like you have two questions here. One about a stack overflow and one about warnings.

Comment: Okay. I understand that it is deprecated, but that is what I need to call, and I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: @NiteShaed-No,it's not deprectaed,it might be that those are not getting used anywhere OR not running even for once in the program. Andreas comment was for humour,you mustn't feel it as deprecated,it is fine and there is somewhere logic error!

Comment: The program says that it is deprecated when I hover my mouse over it. So I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling setbounds from your reshape method would be causing stackoverflowerror.

If you look at the source code of Component class the setBounds method calls the reshape method. So from your reshape method when you call super (Component) class setbounds method then from this Component setbounds method again your reshape overridden method is called which is why there is a recursive call and hence statckoverflowerror. To fix this you need to call super.reshape(...) instead of super.setBounds(..)

A sample code demonstrating this is given below:-

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyClassB obj = new MyClassB();
        obj.reshape(0, 2, 4, 6);
    }

}

class MyClassA {

    public void setBounds(int x,int y,int width,int height) {
        reshape(x, y, width, height); // This calls the child class reshape method if it is overridden and hence can be recursive call

    }

    public void reshape(int x,int y,int width,int height) {

    }
}

class MyClassB extends MyClassA {

    public void reshape (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
    };

}
```

Comment: Okay. But when I try to call reshape from my reshape method, it tells me that it is deprecated.  So, I looked up what it was replaced by, and substitued it in.

Comment: @NiteShaed yes the reshape method is deprecated . But you are actually overriding reshape(..) method in you child class and calling setbounds method which in turn is calling your child class reshape(..) method.

Comment: So, I can use it anyway?  Do I just @SuppressWarnings?

Comment: Why don't you just override `setBounds` instead of overriding a deprecated method?

Comment: @NiteShaed As David says you can just override setBounds and think of calling setMaze() from this overridden method instead of overriding reshape(..) method. But if its a requirement then just dont call super.setBounds from your overridden reshape method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the stack trace, it looks pretty clear: Somewhere in `super.setBounds(..)` `reshape(..)` is called. A recursive error.